# Use parsnip to call glm.nb

Tags: tidymodels

Looking for a wrapper to call negative binomial from MASS package similar to possionreg available in the tidy models environment? Is there a way to call this.

Comment: We don't currently support negative binomial regression but there is [discussion of it in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/35), if you would like to +1 or add to the discussion.